# What is the latest version of Tango Core?

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm getting a Tango Service Outdated error when using some apps, and others just don't seem to be working as well as they should. I have a (deprecated) Tango Core installed, and the closest I can find to a Tango Core app is the about tab of the Tango App Discovery which says my Tango service version is 1.47. If I try to install Tango Core from the Play Store it says my device is incompatible. So, I was wondering if 1.47 is the latest version of Tango Core, I can't seem to find anything but names from Google's websites.

Other info:

```
Tango Development Kit
Kernel version - 
3.10.24-gd25b167
Tango@Atap #1
Tue Nov 29 11:04:29GMT 2016
Build number -
KOT49H.161129
```

Answer (score 0):

On the 11th of July 2017:
I just updated to the last Tango Core version from Google play which is 1.55 and the last sdk version is [Ikariotikos](https://developers.google.com/tango/release-notes).

Comment: Thanks. What platform are you using?

Comment: I am using the Lenovo Phab 2 Pro.

Comment: I'm not able to download the Tango Core from the store, any suggestions?